# The Audio Merge With Sound Design SE Is Now Underway

Tags: discussion

As [previously announced](https://video.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/343/merging-with-social-sound-design-now-in-progress), we're happy to now announce that the merge between Audio in AVP and Sound Design SE is now underway. A system message banner will shortly appear on the main site, alerting folks to what's going on.

For the most part, once you [go create a linked account on Sound](http://sound.stackexchange.com) if you have not already done so, you won't need to do anything else. Posts you've contributed here will soon appear there, as will your reputation and badges as we finish migrations. Just remember, it's *important* that you create an account there if you don't already have one.

There's a [post on meta Sound](https://sound.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/36/the-sound-se-community-is-about-to-get-much-bigger) that details how we're going to be proceeding, it's worth a minute or two to read just so you're up to speed on what's going on. I'll highlight the most important parts here, just in case:

- Moderators on AVP and Sound are now moderators on *both* sites, so that migrations can happen efficiently.
- There's a [special chat room](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/12614/sound-design-avp-merge-project) set up just for the project, feel free to drop in and say hello!
- We expect that this will be mostly complete in about a week.

The most important thing is - ***new sound related questions should be posted to Sound SE - however we will be migrating those that weren't.*** Additionally, we're going to be making use of bulk migration tools to get *most* of the purely or mostly sound related questions over there - there's no need to flag anything *at this point*.

When we're close to saying that we're done, I'll be posting again to ask the community to take a final 'last pass' through their posts and make sure anything that didn't make it over gets flagged for migration.

We will also be sending over any related and active meta discussions during this time, likely *after* the bulk of the main content has been sent over. You should take any *new* meta discussions to [the new meta site](http://meta.sound.stackexchange.com), as well as questions about the migrations themselves.

In short, the best way to help is to *not* create new sound content here, but rather go there instead - this helps us to quickly and efficiently get everything identified and shipped over properly.

We're really excited to see the sound community on Stack Exchange grow due to this opportunity, and for the video community to finally have a place of their own.

***Part two - Video*** will be posted as soon as we've finished the Sound migrations, so stay tuned!

***Update***

A migration path between AVP and Sound Design SE has now been established (one way) for the time being. This will likely remain for at least the next few weeks, as there's bound to be residual mostly sound related questions that just didn't get picked up during the bulk move.

Comment: How about informing all users via e-mail, so that everybody who is not visiting the page daily/weekly/whatever gets this information? I would also highlight "it's important that you create an account there" as bold (or using red color), because it seems to be important!

Comment: @Michael We're .. very .. careful when it comes to sending someone something that they didn't opt into receiving, just as a matter of policy. However, there's a huge bar on the top of the site that will stay in place for a while pointing folks to this, so I'm sure _most_ will see it, and our team is expecting to help a few folks via email after they contact us.

Comment: @TimPost Just to check if I understand this correctly: All sound related questions will be moved to Sound.SE and later all Video question will be moved to another SE as well? Will this dissolve AVP?

Comment: @BartArondson What I'm _likely_ going to do is just re-name _this_ site to "Video", make it video.stackexchange.com, and leave avp.stackexchange.com there as an alias so redirects for migrated questions work. I have to double check sanity of that with Super Dalgas, but the video end of this should be minimal, at least in theory.

Answer (score 1):

I'm having problems logging into to the new sound site - I selected login using stack-exchange data but it doesn't seem to be recognizing it or my password - once in will it automatically pick-up on answers and votes previously posted in AVP and migrated to the new site?

Comment: OK I logged in under google and it worked - thanks for making this fairly seemless!!